# PHP - How to install the latest version of package?

Tags: php, linux, apt

I am trying to install the latest extension/package version on PHP.

I have tried the following on both PHP 8.1 and 7.4 and I am getting the same type of error:

```
sudo apt install php-opcache
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package php-opcache is a virtual package provided by:
  php8.2-opcache 8.2.0~rc1-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php8.1-opcache 8.1.10-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php8.0-opcache 1:8.0.23-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.4-opcache 1:7.4.30-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.3-opcache 7.3.33-6+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.2-opcache 7.2.34-34+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.1-opcache 7.1.33-49+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php7.0-opcache 7.0.33-62+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
  php5.6-opcache 5.6.40-62+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'php-opcache' has no installation candidate
```

I know that I must specify a version, but isn't there some way around this? I am follwoing FIVE separate tutorials on how to install a particular software on my home server and ALL of them are giving me the option to just install a bulk list of packages - same for the video tutorials around the Internet - not a single one of the instructors are specifying a version - so there must be some kind of solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Like it's indicated: `You should explicitly select one to install.`. For PHP 8.1, try to install `php8.1-opcache` and it should fix your problem, I guess.

Comment: It wont ask this is you only have one version of PHP installed, but because you have multiple versions installed it needs a bit more guidance as to which one you want updating

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nope! Both attempts were made on separate VMs - one with freshly installed PHP 8.1 and another one with PHP 7.4

Comment: @Ady I already noted that there must be a way around this, and I am searching at it.

Comment: If you do this, what does it show you? `sudo update-alternatives --list php`

Comment: While that is a tool for programming, your question is not about programming but about Ubuntu system administration. This Q rather belongs on askubuntu.com.

Comment: @RiggsFolly 
/usr/bin/php7.4

Comment: @Ulrich Eckhardt How is this related to Ubuntu and why it shouldn't concern PHP? This is not a programming question, yes, but is a question about the programming language, not the OS itself.

Comment: How to find and install packages is an OS-specific task. It doesn't involve any programming, as you noticed, so it's off-topic here. Even PHP isn't a significant part of the question, the general problem and according solutions are the same for totally different packages.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt just to prove that statement wrong, I downloaded another distro and got the same problem with PHP. I found the solution (and that was not in Ubuntu's package manager but in PHP's) however I will not post it here since I do not think that this threat contributed to anything at all, rather but wasting my time.

Answer (score 0):

try this
apt install php7.4-opcache
and for php8
apt install php8.1-opcache

be sure conflicts maybe occurred when using multiple version with multiple project you have to assign version to virtual host

Comment: I literally said that I know that adding the version will resolve this - but I am looking for solution that works without the versions. I know that this is possible - I just want to learn how.

Comment: without add version you will add default version in repo for your os version , so for that we add version